# From Myanmar or India to Europe overland

Tags: visas, china, russia, pakistan

I am currently in Myanmar, soon going to India, and I have been looking at my options to go to Belgium without a plane for a while now.

I have three options
A) new Delhi cross wagah border into Pakistan, cycle to Quetta and take a police escorte to Zahedan into Iran. Then take trains through Iran and Turkey into Europe
- problems might be safety in Baluchistan and around Pakistan Iran border

B) new Delhi cross wagah border into Pakistan, cycle to border with China and head to Tajikistan, Kyrgyzstan and Kazakhstan. Take a train to Moscow and a bus to Europe.
- problems might be russian and Chinese visa and the weather

C) only recently considered going back to Thailand and then Laos to cross the border with China to head to Mongolia and Russia

Could you help me out with info on safety, visas and borders

Comment: Quite a lot of people take the Transsiberian Railway for tourism. Once you reach it, the rest should be quite safe.

Comment: @Joeri Depuydt What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

This site is not a travel agency, but I'll take a stab at this.

I'd think that your first option is doable. What the current situation is in western Pakistan, I don't know. But if you travel in an organised convoy, you should be fine. <strike>Keep in mind that there currently is no train running across the Iranian/Turkish border, because of the conflict in Syria.</strike> You could also get into Turkey via Azerbaijan and then Georgia.

As far as I'm aware, your second option goes through a crossing (Pakistan to China) that's not open all year and not always open to foreigners, but my information on this is flimsy. And you might have to travel to capitals to get visas to cross into the next country from Pakistan to China to the Stans.

I don't see any practical issue with your third option. You could take a train from Beijing all the way to Moscow.

Comment: There actually are trains from Turkey to Iran. These trains do not come anywhere near Syria. This page has the info: https://www.seat61.com/India-overland.htm

Comment: @KristvanBesien: You're right that the train is running, but you were not looking at the right page; The Ankara to Tehran train is running again since August 2019. Details here: https://www.seat61.com/Iran.htm